# Where can I find willing open source Android contributers

Tags: android, open-source

I am writing an application which I hope to build a client for in Android.
However, I am fairly inexperienced in Android development and am looking for droid devs who would be willing to contribute to my open source client.

Where can I find such people? I dont care where they are, just as long as they have a strong grasp on the english language.

*edit: to clarify - I am not trying to recruit people through stackoverflow, merely where such people would register as willing contributors looking for a project, so I can look through their profiles and get in contact with them.

Comment: So what kind of application are we talking about? Maybe you'll get some interesting people if you are more specific.

Comment: It is similar to the Quota app

Comment: Double your money!  Just send $14.95 and a self addressed stamped envelope to PO BOX 31337!

Comment: Work hard to make your application good, and popular, and they will come to you.

Comment: Hey Steven, I am willing to contribute android open source projects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a job-board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would post you project on an open source repository website like [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [Google Code](http://code.google.com/). And start making commits and post information on the app. Most open source projects start with a few devs and the community kicks in once you have a decent user base. I feel like the best way to recruit people to to put your project out there and show people that it has potential. Then people will want to contribute to it.

Comment: I will accept this answer, but I still dont think it answers my question completely. (See the edit to the question)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [Android contributors group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/android-contrib).